# .media-right vs. .pull-right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on removing some deprecated items from our bootstrap instance and ran into this issue. When changing the View more link from .pull-right to .media-right it seems it loses the float that had previously been put on the .pull-right class. Am I using the media-right class incorrectly? I can't seem to get it to match up to how it had been working with this.

It doesn't quite have the styling but you can see the alignment on the last link element when you change from pull-right to media-right

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/07w13nL8/9/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahmuA.jpg

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="media media-box">
        <div class="media-box-body">
            <ul class="media-list">
                <li class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="...">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
                <a class="pull-right" href="#">View More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show code in jsfiddle..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue. What you are doing is using `col-md-3` and inside that you want things to float left and float right. Unfortunately though 'content' is full width even if its floated.  so the view more link goes under.

this is how you would do it

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <ul>
                <li class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="...">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
  <a href="#">View More</a>
</div>
```

obviously this botstrap is responsive at certain width its going to be under eachother. 
[Bootply example below](http://www.bootply.com/render/zfYwaGjSl9)

Comment: In trying this and swapping "pull-right" out for the "media-right" it still doesn't seem to display correctly?

Comment: a screenshot would help

Comment: It wouldn't let me post one specificially to the ticket, I figured out a workaround http://imgur.com/tuSJSYU